# Retain numpy mask when inserting arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, mask

I am attempting to use numpy masked arrays to filter "no data" from raster images. The array calculations I am doing subtract the values of adjacent pixels (see [Applying functions to multidimensional numpy arrays without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336303/applying-functions-to-multidimensional-numpy-arrays-without-loops/34341400#34341400)), but I need to ignore no data values. For example, with the array:

```
array = np.array([[78, 72, 69, 71, 58, 49],
                 [74, 67, 56, 49, 46, 50],
                 [69, 53, 44, 37, -9999, -9999],
                 [64, 58, 55, 22, 33, 24],
                 [68, 61, 47, 21, 16, 19],
                 [74, 53, 34, 12, 11, 12]])
```

Lets say -9999 is a no data value. So I mask the array as follows:

```
array = np.ma.masked_where(array == -9999, array, False)
```

This produces an expected result. I then need to calculate the difference each element against it's surrounding 8 neighbors. So for the "lower right" neighbor, this would be (ignoring edge pixels here):

```
result = array[1: 5, 1: 5] - array[2: 6, 2: 6]
```

This also produces the result I intend:

```
[[23, 19, --, --],
 [-2, 22, 4, --],
 [11, 34, 6, 14],
 [27, 35, 10, 4]]
```

However, when I insert the result array as a dimension of an empty array, the mask is lost from -9999, and worse still, the elements that "inherited" the mask ([1, 3] & [1, 4]) are inserted with their original values.

```
gradient = np.empty((8, 4, 4), dtype = np.int)
gradient[0] = result
```

I can mask out the -9999 values again, but as I will be applying the argmax function across axis 0 of the gradient array, the retention of the original values causes issues. I am looking for a way to either insert the result array as it appears above, or an alternative method to the masking to exclude neighbor elements matching the null value and/or replace the value in the result.

Comment: A masked array has a data array and a mask array.  `gradient` is not masked, so only gets the data part. Masking is fragile, and is only maintained by mask aware operations.

Comment: Explanation makes sense. I'll avoid it for what I'm working on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use nan (nan = not a number) values instead of -9999:

```
array[array == -9999] = np.nan
```

then do your calculation. Every value which is derived from this value should also be nan.

Comment: So I should set the dtype of all arrays to np.float? This is fine, as my input arrays are often floating point anyway. With np.nan in place, If I try gradient[0].argmin(axis=0), the result is [1 0 0 0], which I think means nan is being considered. Is that correct, and is there a way to exclude nan from such calculations?

Comment: This question does this with nanargmin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821072/is-there-a-better-way-of-making-numpy-argmin-ignore-nan-values So your solution to use nan instead of a mask works for me.